# Сценарий автоматической настройки прокси(proxy)

Tags: windows, сеть, реестр, прокси

У меня в настройках параметров локальной сети периодически часто выскакивает галочка напротив "Использовать сценарий автоматической настройки". Хотелось бы как автоматизировать отключение данного бага , ибо самому приходиться заходить и вырубать эту галочку.[image: Галочка]

Все что нашел в интернете только отключает сам прокси :  `reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

В каталоге реестра `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` не нашел параметра который бы отключал эту галочку.
[image: реестр]

З.Ы. Этот баг гуляет по нашей сети уже который год , либо из за нехотения  сетевиков либо просто недостаточно квалификации ))))
Спасибо за ответы коллеги !

Comment: На SO [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544270/) есть. Либо [Remove the Auto-Config Proxy URL](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-the-Auto-Config-2e4a660f)

Comment: что такое SO ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отключения этой галочки надо в "Командной строке" написать:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
```